# Decode Base64 into UTF-8 rather then single byte encoded text

Tags: emacs, base64

Here are things that I've tried:

Added annotation to the buffer: `#-*- coding: utf-8; -*-`

<kbd>M-x M-m c</kbd>, select `utf-8` from the list, then <kbd>M-x</kbd>`base64-decode-region`.

Here's what the buffer shows: `\327\252\327\234 \327\220\327\221\327\231\327\221`. What it "should" be showing is `תל אביב`. The source string looks like this: `16rXnCDXkNeR15nXkQ==`

Comment: Do you mean `C-x RET c`? Have you tried it the other way round? First decode and then switch to UTF-8.

Comment: I assume, you have the appropriate fonts installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buffer's coding system specifies the coding system used when reading the content from a file and when writing the content to a file.  IOW, your "coding: utf-8" thingy only indicates how to decode the ASCII source string (which does not require any special decoding since it's ASCII, but that base64 string could be surrounded by non-ASCII text).

What you need is to call `decode-coding-region` after having called `base64-decode-region`.

**Edit**

Here are correspondent defuns:

```lisp
(defun base64-decode-utf8-region (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region start end)
    (base64-decode-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (decode-coding-region (point-min) (point-max) 'utf-8)))

(defun base64-encode-utf8-region (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region start end)
    (encode-coding-region (point-min) (point-max) 'utf-8)
    (base64-encode-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Comment: ASCII only contains chars <128, so there's no code page involved.